# GDAL Python Function to convert vector files from shapefile to KML

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, kml

I want to convert a shapefile with polygon to KML file using GDAL Python.
For this I created a fuction with two arguments (input and output) and it works, but points in polygon are switched (X in KML is Y in SHP and Y in KML is X in SHP).
In ogr.ogeometry is a method SwapXY but it is for points not polygons.

https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#SwapXY

I try to export polygon to array of points but I didn't find any fuction for it.
After that I create geometry from WKT and export to KML but I don't know how to save it into output file (not as text file but KML with georeferences).
I don't want use subprocess with ogr2ogr, because it is a system dependency.

Here is a code:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def __convert_shp_to_kml(shp_file: pathlib.Path, kml_file: pathlib.Path = None):
        """
        Convert shp (shape file) to kml file.

        :param shp_file: path to shp file
        :type shp_file: pathlib.Path
        :return: True if conversion is correct
        :rtype: bool
        """
        assert shp_file.exists() is True, logging.error("File: " + str(shp_file) + " not exist.")
        if kml_file is None:
            kml_file = str(shp_file).replace(shp_file.suffix, ".kml")
            kml_file_name = str(shp_file.stem)
        else:
            kml_file_name = str(kml_file.stem)
            kml_file = str(kml_file)

        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
        dataset = driver.Open(str(shp_file))
        layer = dataset.GetLayer()
        spatial_ref = layer.GetSpatialRef()
        epsg_code: int = int(spatial_ref.GetAttrValue('AUTHORITY', 1))

        output_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
        out_ds = output_driver.CreateDataSource(kml_file)
        output_data_set = osr.SpatialReference()
        output_data_set.ImportFromEPSG(epsg_code)
        out_layer = out_ds.CreateLayer(kml_file_name, output_data_set, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

        ds = ogr.Open(str(shp_file))
        if ds is None:
            logging.warning(str(shp_file) + "ds is empty")
        lyr = ds.GetLayer()
        for feat in lyr:
            geom_poly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(str(feat.GetGeometryRef()))
            print(geom_poly.ExportToKML())
            out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_layer.GetLayerDefn())
            out_feat.SetGeometry(geom_poly)
            out_layer.CreateFeature(out_feat)
            out_layer.SyncToDisk()
        return True
```

Comment: I would use [`gdal.VectorTranslate`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate) (like the commandline `ogr2ogr` tool).

Comment: Please tell explicitly what coordinate order you have now in KML. I suppose it is latitude-longitude, but confirm. SwapXY takes in geometry by the API document. What makes you think it works only for points? Also read https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn and try `SetAxisMappingStrategy?(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)`.

Comment: I use ```gdal.VectorTranslate``` as method:
```srcDS = gdal.OpenEx(str(shp_file))
        gdal.VectorTranslate(destNameOrDestDS=kml_file, srcDS=srcDS, format='KML')```
Warnings
First
```Warning 1: The output driver does not seem to natively support Integer64 type for field tessellate. Converting it to Real instead. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.```
Second
```Warning 1: The output driver does not seem to natively support Integer64 type for field extrude. Converting it to Real instead. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.```